# onActivityResult not called under API level 17

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a class for uploading image to server but i can't choose image from gallery.It's properly working on API Level +17 but not working on API Level -17

thoose are my codes

CustomJavascriptClass

```
public String uploadImage(){
    Activity activity = (Activity)context;
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");       
    activity.startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 100);
...
```

MainActivity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    if(requestCode == 100){
        try{
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();            
            Log.i("File", filePath);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
                HappyJavaScriptInterface.attachment = new File(filePath);      
                HappyJavaScriptInterface.uploadProcess = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                HappyJavaScriptInterfaceUnder17.attachment = new File(filePath);      
                HappyJavaScriptInterfaceUnder17.uploadProcess = 1;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
                HappyJavaScriptInterface.uploadProcess = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                HappyJavaScriptInterfaceUnder17.uploadProcess = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working properly on android 4.2.2 emulator but not working on 2.3.3

Thanks

Comment: The problem is `onActivityResult` is not called or what?

Comment: yes onActivityResult is not called for API Level -17

Comment: is it possible that You have also implementet two ways of startActivityForResult()?

Comment: they have different classes

Comment: they are same methods but different classes

Comment: sorry to ask again, but sure that You on both call startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 100); ? because, there is a startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) which is added in later APIs (API 16)...

Comment: startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) is added API 16 but i'm using startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

Comment: and from which object does HappyJavaScriptInterface and HappyJavaScriptInterfaceUnder17 come from? Whats does this custom class extends?

Comment: they extends Object (not any class inherited)

Comment: maybe the issue is in one of them....can You post them?

Comment: HappyJavaScriptInterface is working properly. HappyJavaScriptInterfaceUnder17 methods are working fine it's opening gallery for pick image but i pick image not calling onActivityResult event

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:noHistory="false"` in your manifest for `MainActivity`

Comment: it depends if he hast set it. Usually, if noHistory is not specified in the manifest, the default value is false.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs you mean is false, i know but sometimes it happens to have a weird behavior, for example some times i couldn't export my apk on android studio because the flag `debuggable` wasn't set to false, but it wasn't even set to true :-)